# I dono what is the error in my RegController . It does not insert Values in to my Mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

This is my Register.jsp code. I am creating a student portal information project . When i try to register it accepts the values and also assign it to the variables in the RegController servlet but it is not inserted in to Mysql database .

```
   <%-- 
    Document   : Register
    Created on : Apr 23, 2014, 11:54:12 PM
    Author     : hari
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Register Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="register" action="RegController">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Username" size="15" placeholder="Enter the Username" required="required"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" size="15" placeholder="Enter the Name" required="required"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Father Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fathername" size="15" placeholder="Enter the Father Name" required="required"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="age" size="5" placeholder="Enter Your Age" required="required"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="address" size="15" placeholder="Enter the Address" required="required"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Contact</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="contact" size="15" placeholder="Enter the Contact" required="required"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Department</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="dept" size="8" placeholder="Enter the Department" required="required"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Qualification</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="qualification" size="15" placeholder="Enter the Qualification" required="required"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>College</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="college" size="50" placeholder="Enter the College Name" required="required"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="Password" size="15" placeholder="Enter the Password" required="required"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></td>
                    <td>To Login<a href="index.jsp">Click here</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

This my Servlet Code RegController.java

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author hari
 */
@WebServlet(name = "RegController", urlPatterns = {"/RegController"})
public class RegController extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        //out.println("name"+name);
        String Username=request.getParameter("Username");
        String age=request.getParameter("age");
        String fathername=request.getParameter("fathername");
        String address=request.getParameter("address");
        String phno=request.getParameter("contact");
        String dept=request.getParameter("dept");
        String qualification=request.getParameter("qualification");
        String college=request.getParameter("college");
        String Password=request.getParameter("Password");

       String DB_url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYFIRSTPROJECT";
       String JDBC_Driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
       String UserDB="root" ;
       String PassDB="";
        int i=1;
        Connection conn=null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
        //Statement stmt=null;
        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //out.println("Connection");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_url,UserDB,PassDB);
        String sql="insert into users VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        //stmt=conn.createStatement();
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstmt.setString(1,Username);
        //stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        pstmt.setString(2,Password);
        pstmt.setString(3,name);
        pstmt.setString(4,fathername);
        pstmt.setString(5,address);
        pstmt.setString(6,age);
        pstmt.setString(7,phno);
        pstmt.setString(8,dept);
        pstmt.setString(9,qualification);
        pstmt.setString(10,college);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        pstmt.close();
        //conn.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
        try{
        if(pstmt!=null)
            pstmt.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){}
        try{
        if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){se.printStackTrace();}

        }
        //if(i<=1){
          //  out.println("Error"+i+Username);}
        //else{
            System.out.println("Registered Successfully");
            response.sendRedirect("Welcome.jsp");
        //}
    }   

}
```

Netbeans doesn't show any errors . Can anybody help plzzz....

Comment: Are you getting all values from jsp page ? Have try to print it ?

Comment: Yes...i got all the values..

Comment: Then try to execute your query directly to mysql like `insert into users VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)` on place of `?` put appropriate values. Then post me that what happen ?

Comment: Thanks Got it....the error is...Phno has value Null. So the sql fails...when i changed it...the query works perfectly...Thank you.. :) :)

Comment: If Your problem solved them you can accept the answer so other will not visit your solved quesion..